# Search for string in pandas data frame and get column index

Tags: pandas, indexing

I am trying to get a column index by searching for a string. I have tried a code like this "Units_Conv.columns.get_loc(Current_Unit)". Current_Unit is a string variable. But give me error as
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD27p.png)

My dataframe is as below:
[Data Frame Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLPpY.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

I want to clarify my question again with following:

I want to search for a text and get column index. In the example, I am searching for 'kg / hr' (note the lower case) and get column name 'KG / HR' and find index of that column ie 6. Finally I looking for a index. Also I found out that I need to searching for a specific text in all columns except the first column (ie index 0). I hope we can find solution.

Thanks

Comment: I have even tried something like this " (Units_Conv == 'Kg / hr').any().idxmax()" but it gives me wrong column name.

Answer (score 0):

`df.columns` will give you a list of columns names it have nothing to do with filtering and searching.

use: `df[df['KG / HR']=='string']' to make a filter, **and make sure to write it in UPPER case** because python distinguish between upper and lower case.

if you want to just get index of a matching string then use:

```
df.index[df['KG / HR']==current_unit].tolist()
```

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I was not clear. I want to search for a text and get column index. In the example, I am searching for 'kg / hr' (note the lower case) and get column name 'KG / HR'  and find index of that column ie 6. Finally I looking for a index. Also I found out that I need to searching for a specific text in all columns except the first column (ie index 0). I hope we can find solution.